# Laravel excel export list in list object maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Hi I want to export list of people with all theirs childrens in them to excel. I'm using maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel plugin and its quite easy to export users collection but I need to include users every children inside that row. Its something like [{Name, Age, Gender, Job, Children[{name, age, gender, etc...}], Birthday, etc...}]. And how do I change order of the data column displayed on excel like if I want to switch datas on Age and Gender. Thank you!

Comment: Please share the code you already wrote in your question so we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WithMapping` 
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html

```
<?php
    public function map($user): array
    {
        //create initial array with user data in order that you want columns to be
        $data = [
           $user->name
           ...
        ];
        // the same way you should crate headers (if you have). But instead of values you should create column name
        foreach($user->children as $child){
            array_push($data, $child->name, $child->birthday, $child->...., ..., ...); //and so on
        }

        // returned data should be 1 level array as each item is a row in the table
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: It's kinda working but when $user->children has 2 or more items then only one is shown why is that? I need all those childrens to span a row inside or below its parent as well